# Power Bi- how do I convert my date column in power query without getting an error

Tags: datetime, powerbi, powerquery

I am getting errors in some rows when I try to convert my Date column in Power query. the Date column is set to TEXT data type but I need it to be in DATE type.

I tried changing the data type to from TEXT to DATE, but I am getting errors in some rows. I will drop the screenshots.

[image: screenshot of the raw dataset]

[image: Result I got after changing data type to DATE screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're being parsed using the wrong locale (even the ones parsed as dates are incorrect). Click the ABC icon in the column header and parse with locale at the bottom of the menu.

[image]

Comment: regarding the locale itself - the format of the column seems to be `m/d/y`, which could be US locale

Comment: I agree - that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your country date settings are messed up because 4/10/2013 is evaluating as 4-Oct-2013, which means that 3/16/2013 is trying to use 16 as the month. You need locale option at bottom

see images at https://www.excelcampus.com/powerquery/power-query-date-errors-settings/ pasted below

[image]